# what is the best method to replace values in a foreach call

Tags: php, arrays, replace, foreach

I am using ***'foreach'*** to get these values from an array

```
[{"country_id":"340","country_name":"World Cup 2018","league_id":"1736","league_name":" Group A"},{"country_id":"340","country_name":"World Cup 2018","league_id":"1737","league_name":" Group B"},{"country_id":"340","country_name":"World Cup 2018","league_id":"1738","league_name":" Group C"}]

<?php foreach ( $result as $comp ):
    echo $comp->league_name;
<?php endif;?>
```

What is the best method I can use to replace and translate the ***'league_name'*** with my own translation. should I implement this with ***'switch'*** or there is a better way to it?

```
 switch ($comp->league_name)
 {            
     case 'Group A':
         echo 'Grupo A';
         break;
     case 'Group B':
         echo 'Grupo B';
         break;  
 }
```

Am looking for a more efficient way in which I can call such a function anytime to translate different values, without repeating the same switch function every time.

Comment: you could make a translate function

Comment: Personally, as a quick workaround, i would use a dictionary associative array file that would be included and used to retrieve the associated key(s) value Example: https://3v4l.org/6Rv8V For reuse you can declare a variable using an `include` file that contains only `<?php return array();` which would be optimized by the OP Cache. However the answers that would be provided from this question would be highly opinionated include the use of third-party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with translation of strings is to use [gettext](http://php.net/gettext), which is specifically designed to be both fast and memory efficient when dealing with large translation tables.

The idea is that you create a text-based [list of strings and their translations (*known as a PO file*)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#PO-Files), and then compile them to a [compact binary file (*or MO file*)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Binaries), which can be loaded into memory once and used to quickly retrieve translations from anywhere in your code.